# How to use drawer navigator in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to implement drawer navigator in my react native application. I have used the openDrawer() function in the component that should open the drawer. However on clicking the component the drawer is directly launching the screen inside the drawer rather than simply opening the drawer. Is the way i am using the navigator wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Navigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer,createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {View,Platform,StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import LoginForm from './Components/LoginForm';
import TheatreList from './Components/TheatreList';
import Menu from './Components/Menu';
import EmployeeEdit from './Components/EmployeeEdit';
import CartScreen from './Components/CartScreen';
import Screen from './Components/Screen';
import ShoppingCartIcon from './Components/ShoppingCartIcon';
import PaymentScreen from './Components/PaymentScreen';
import Screen1 from './Screen/Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen/Screen2';

import * as Expo from 'expo';


const Navigator = createStackNavigator({

       TheatreList:{
        screen:TheatreList
    } , 

       Login: {
      screen:LoginForm
    },


    Menu: {
        screen:Menu
    },
    Cart: {
        screen:CartScreen
    },
    PaymentScreen:{
      screen:PaymentScreen
    }, 
  },
{
    headerMode: 'none',
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
    },
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'TheatreList'
  }
  );

const AppDrawerNavigator=createDrawerNavigator(
{
  Navigator,
    Screen1:{
      screen:Screen1
    },
    Screen2:{
      screen:Screen2
    }
});

const RootNav=createSwitchNavigator({

  Navigator,
  AppDrawerNavigator

});

export default createAppContainer(RootNav);
```

ProfileIcon.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Picker,Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

const ProfileIcon = (props) => (
  <View style ={{
        position:'absolute',
        top:0,
        left:0,
        right:5,
       // padding:7,
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 40/2,
        border: '1px solid #c45653',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginLeft: 15,padding:7}}>
     <Icon name="menu" onPress={() => props.navi.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}  style ={{fontSize:50, position:'absolute', top:0, right:0,width:40, color:'#fe003a'}} />
</View>
)

export default ProfileIcon;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make nested stacknavigators. Inside AppDrawerNavigator ,call your Navigator stack

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator({
DrawerMenu: { screen: DrawerMenu },
Home: { screen: Home },
},
 {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    })
 });

 const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
 RootNavigator: {
    screen: RootNavigator, //rootNavigator
    navigationOptions: { title: 'titleHere' },
 },
 },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'RootNavigator',
    drawerPosition: 'Left',
    backBehavior: 'none',
    contentComponent: props => <DrawerMenu {...props} />,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
},
);

const LoginNavigator = createStackNavigator({
   Login: {
    screen: Login,
     navigationOptions: {
        drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
        headerStyle: { },    
        headerTitleStyle: {  },
        title: 'Title'
    }
  },
})

export default createSwitchNavigator({
   AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,  //SplashScreen
   LoginNavigator: LoginNavigator,
   Drawer: Drawer,
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
})
```